# If $f(x)=2x^2+2x-4$ and $g(x)=x^2-x+2$, Find the number of integral values of $x\in[1,10]$ such that $\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{g(x)}\ge \sqrt{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $f(x)=2x^2+2x-4$ and $g(x)=x^2-x+2$, Find the number of integral values of $x\in[1,10]$ such that $\sqrt{f(x)}+\sqrt{g(x)}\ge \sqrt{2}$

I tried squaring two times to remove the square root and ended up with a biquadratic which is difficult to analyse. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: let me ask a dumb question, what is "integral value"?

Comment: @frank000 Integer values

Comment: hmm then just plug in 1,2,3,...,10 and check... no?

Comment: @frank000 I know that. Is there any other method other than brute force?

Comment: Calculus or completing square will tell you $f$ and $g$ are both increasing on [1,10], so as long as you find one all larger integers are solutions. On the other hand it's easy to check 1 does not satisfy but 2 does.

Comment: @frank000 thats better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39828/discussion-between-frank000-and-aditya-dev).

Comment: OK when I made the comment the question on the right hand side was 2 not $\sqrt 2$...just to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both parabolas are increasing and non-negative on the interval $[1,10]$ therefore so is the sum of their square roots.

Since $x=1$ is an integral solution, then so is every integer in the interval $[1,10]$.